# AWS sagemaker - import libraries from other sagemaker notebooks in thr same folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, amazon-sagemaker

Started using AWS sage maker recently. I have a couple of notebooks that hold the code for few functions that i would like to use in another notebook of sagemaker. I tried importing these functions with import but didn t work. Any suggestions. The modules are in the same folder as the other notebook

I tried mane combinations of the following without success

```
From feutures import *
```

How can i add external functions to my project? Does the function need to be in a   `.py` format or   `.ipnb` is also fine?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using SageMaker. You can install `ipynb` by `pip install ipynb` then import the function in another notebook by:

`from ipynb.fs.full.YOUR_NOTEBOOK_NAME`